# Qt Library 'mysql' is not defined

Tags: mysql, linux, qt

I have a problem with Qt connecting with MySql, when i run this code

```cpp
    QSqlDatabase DBObject = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    DBObject.setHostName("localhost");
    DBObject.setDatabaseName("SingleDB");
    DBObject.setUserName("root");
    DBObject.setPassword("abc123");
    bool ok = DBObject.open();
```

and I got this... QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
[image: QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded]

I Have already done this also:

```sh
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient
```

and

```sh
/home/wrm/Qt/5.12.3/gcc_64/bin/qmake "INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/local/include" "LIBS+=-L/usr/local/lib -lmysqlclient_r" mysql.pro
```

and here i have this error: Project ERROR: Library 'mysql' is not defined
[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Install `libqt4-sql-mysql` for Qt4 or `libqt5sql5-mysql` for Qt5

Comment: Hi Michael... have done already... but still not working :/

Comment: and problem remains the same... Library 'mysql' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to install `mysql-devel`.

According to the Qt Docs [QMYSQL for MySQL 4 and higher](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qmysql):

> How to Build the QMYSQL Plugin on Unix and macOS
>
> You need the MySQL header files, as well as the shared library libmysqlclient.so. Depending on your Linux distribution, you may need to install a package which is usually called "mysql-devel".

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't have a readily available answer, so answering this old question:

Aside from needing development files as pointed above (like `apt install libmysqlclient-dev`), you need to generate a config:

```
# Just for making my snippet work. Feel free to hardcode paths.
export QTDIR=/home/you/Qt/
export QTVERSION=5.9.5

cd $QTDIR/$QTVERSION/Src/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers
$QTDIR/$QTVERSION/gcc_64/bin/qmake sqldrivers.pro
cd mysql
make
make install # if you want; it installs it in the bin dir of $QTVERSION
```

In the past, this was not necessary for Qt 5.5 (where I did this last time).

On a side note, there is no longer a special thread-safe version of `libmysqlclient` (`libmysqlclient_r`). It's just one one. Last time I ran into that link error, I just edited the generate `Makefile` to use the non-_r.